# Is it possible to use distccmon-text to see which distcc hosts are up and ready to work?

Tags: distcc

When I run distccmon-text 1 it creates a new empty line one time per second even though I (should) have one distcc daemon up and running.

Is it possible to list the host nodes in my ~/.distcc/hosts which are up and running, ready to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where your distcc directory is. If it's not in `~/.distcc` you have to declare `DISTCC_DIR` beforehand:

`DISTCC_DIR=/some/where/over/the/rainbow distccmon-text`

Also if the client isn't sending out requests to servers, you won't see any output.